# How do I center an embedded SVG File?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using an embedded SVG file as the top element on my page. (a header?)

It loads just fine, but nothing I try seems to get it centered.

Here's what I'm using at the start of the **body**:

```
<embed src="images/bannertest.svg" width="1180" height="200" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

I've wrapped it up in a DIV and used CSS to "margin:auto" but  can't get it to budge without just padding it.  The problem is that it goes wonky when I resize the window.

Comment: Reference:
http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <embed src="images/bannertest.svg" width="1180" height="200" type="image/svg+xml"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .parent{
     display:block;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
```

or use this css

```
 .parent embed{
      display:table;
      margin:0 auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am adding code here. Check it may be it helps you..

HTML:

```
<div>
<img class="papa" height="100" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
div { text-align:center}
</style>
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6sRR2/

Hope. It Helps You :)